# when I call join() in a queue, and task_done() has done, but this program still running

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I write this code to practice the Queue in Python with thread. when count is 10 or not big integer. it can run correctly, but when count is 1000, this code cannot stop, or sometimes it ended but the queue still not empty. I don't know how to fix it. please help.

```
import threading
import queue
import random
import time


class Creater(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        global count
        while count < 1000:
            print(threading.current_thread().name, 'is running==', count,
                  '==times')
            inputQueue()
            count += 1


class Consumer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        while not q.empty():
            data = outQueue()
            print(threading.current_thread().name, 'get a data:', data)
            print('queue still has', q.qsize())
            q.task_done()


def inputQueue():
    global q
    q.put(random.randint(0, 1000))


def outQueue():
    data = q.get()
    return data


count = 0
q = queue.Queue()
creater = Creater('creater')
consumer = Consumer('consumer')
startFlag = time.time()
creater.start()
consumer.start()
creater.join()
q.join()
spendTime = time.time() - startFlag
print('now Queue size:', q.qsize())
print('creater total run', count, 'times')
print('Finished in', spendTime)
```

and result sometimes likes this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k6ty.png)

when i type ctrl + c in the terminal, it shows some error info like this:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "xxx.py", line 57, in <module>
  q.join()
File "/home/everglow/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/queue.py", line 83, in join
  self.all_tasks_done.wait()
File "/home/everglow/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 295, in wait
  waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

and now, I think may be it is the `task_done()` could not call `q.join()`,
so, the main thread always waiting. but I don't know this idea is right or wrong. and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Your traceback has `consumer.join()`, but your code doesn't. You've pasted something wrong.

Comment: thank you, I run the code over and over again, I am so careless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your consumer loop `while not q.empty():` can sometimes end if the consumer manages to temporarily empty the queue even though the creator is still running and puts more items on the queue afterwards. Therefore you should find a different way to end the loop, such as counting the number of items consumed and ending when it reaches 1000.

Comment: I see, sometimes, the queue just have a few numbers, while the consumer running,  pull the numbers, it will end because soon the queue is empty.